# typescript: Using get / set for public function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I see that get and set are used for defining getters and setters. Is there a way I can use the name `get` or `set` for a public function. For example, say I have a DB operation and I like to name method `get`

which gives error `error TS1008: Unexpected token; '{' expected.`

```
export interface IReq {
 get: (r:string) => Object;
}

export class Req implements IReq{
  constructor(){
    this.get = (r) => this.getImpl(r);
  } 

get: (r:string) => Object; //gives error  error TS1008: Unexpected token; '{' expected.

private getImpl(r:string) => Object {
//...
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` is a contextual keyword in typescript and will not impede when used out of context. The following compiles fine:

```
export interface IReq {
    get: (r:string) => Object;
}

export class Req implements IReq{
    constructor(){
        this.get = (r) => this.getImpl(r);
    } 

    get: (r:string) => Object; // No error

    private getImpl(r:string): Object {
        return {};
    }
}
```

[Try it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=export%20interface%20IReq%20%7B%0D%0A%09get:%20%28r:string%29%20=%3E%20Object;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20Req%20implements%20IReq%7B%0D%0A%09constructor%28%29%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.get%20=%20%28r%29%20=%3E%20this.getImpl%28r%29;%0D%0A%09%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%09get:%20%28r:string%29%20=%3E%20Object;%20//%20No%20error%0D%0A%0D%0A%09private%20getImpl%28r:string%29:%20Object%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%7B%7D;%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D)

[image: usage]

Comment: thanks. it was a webstorm issue I guess. If I use `get: (r:string) => Object;` it shows error, but tsc compiles fine. if, I do  `gett: (r:string) => Object;`, webstorm has no error :-(

Comment: it doesn't detect `get` as a public var, as it complains `unresolved variable get`, if I just paste your code into IDE.

Comment: @bsr attached a screenshot so you can see it works fine in TS playground. Would appreciate if you can report a bug to the webstorm team here : http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB